# How to extract word in java using regex

Tags: java, regex

Suppose I have a string

```java
String s = The | community | office | system | is here to help you with specific coding, algorithm, or language problems.
```

How can I extract all the words from string `s` into a list which is between the pipe delimiter?

So the list should save `community, office, system`.

I thought of using the following pattern. Will it work?

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(\\|\\w+)").matcher(s);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```java
\|\s*(\w+)(?=\s*\|)
\|\s*(.*?)(?=\s*\|)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2Vlqfv/1) and [regex #2 demo](https://regex101.com/r/2Vlqfv/2). *Details*:

- `\|` - a  `|` char
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(\w+)` - Group 1: one or more word chars
- `(.*?)` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `(?=\s*\|)` - a positive lookahead that matches a location that is immediately followed with zero or more whitespaces and a `|` char.

See a [Java demo](https://ideone.com/ppM9CC) and a [Java #2 demo](https://ideone.com/QWgvVZ):

```java
String s = "The | community | office | system | is here to help you with specific coding, algorithm, or language problems.";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\|\\s*(\\w+)(?=\\s*\\|)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); 
} 
// => community
//    office
//    system

// The second pattern demo:
String s = "The | community section | office section  | system section  | is here to help you with specific coding, algorithm, or language problems.";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\|\\s*(.*?)(?=\\s*\\|)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); 
}
// => community section
//    office section
//    system section
```

Comment: It will not for ```The | community section | office section  | system section  | is here to help you with specific coding, algorithm, or language problems.```

Comment: @Beginner The second one will, see https://ideone.com/QWgvVZ

Comment: Ok got it so i need to use ```.*?```

Comment: @Beginner And if the text may contain line breaks, use `Pattern.DOTALL` when compiling the pattern, i.e. `Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\|\\s*(.*?)(?=\\s*\\|)", Pattern.DOTALL);`.